# EMS light and lack of power

Tags: cel, volvo, s40

I have a Volvo s40 1.6D. I left engine running on idle for 20mins or longer, then drove off. At this point the car lacked acceleration but still able to run at 70mph and idle as smooth as normal. EMS light now permanently on. Suggestions on what may have happened and possible cure?

Comment: Welcome, thanks for bringing your question! If you could add more detail it would be helpful. For example, the year of the car, the milage on it, recent work, any testing you've done – for example have you had the codes from the EMS read? All of that can be helpful.

Comment: Er, What's an EMS?

Comment: Year is 2007. 46,477, Serviced annually (booked for Weds). I have not done any testing but having seen a few uTube clips I have located the diagnostic port. I don't have a reader.

Comment: I have had my garage investigate. They indicated a possible DPF/Particle filter blocked and need kit to Smoke Test Filter to clarify readings. Suggest go to Volvo to undertake this. Guess I'll have to do this as I have no acceleration and not easy driving prolonged periods in this mode.